# how metamacro_if_eq works in extobjc

Tags: objective-c

Read at the source code  https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc/blob/master/extobjc/metamacros.h#L158

```
// expands to true
metamacro_if_eq(0, 0)(true)(false)
```

when is expand the macro metamacro_if_eq(0, 0) manually, i get the following

```
metamacro_if_eq0(0) (true) (false)
```

continue expanding.

```
metamacro_if_eq0_0() (true) (false)
```

go on.

```
metamacro_consume_ (true) (false)

metamacro_consume is defined as: 
#define metamacro_consume_(...)  // why nothing here ?
```

then how can I get the expected value of "true" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your production is incorrect. The operations go like this:

```
metamacro_if_eq(0, 0)(true)(false)

metamacro_concat(metamacro_if_eq, 0)(0)(true)(false)

metamacro_concat_(metamacro_if_eq, 0)(0)(true)(false)

metamacro_if_eq0(0)(true)(false)

metamacro_concat(metamacro_if_eq0_, 0)(true)(false)

metamacro_concat_(metamacro_if_eq0_, 0)(true)(false)

// You made a mistake at this point.

metamacro_if_eq0_0(true)(false)

true metamacro_consume_(false)

true
```

After the second round of concatenation, `true` becomes the argument to `metamacro_if_eq0_0()`. The argument(s) to that macro is/are left in its place. `metamacro_consume_()` takes any numer of arguments and resolves to nothing.